# How to use different images iOS 6 and iOS 7 in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I want to support my app in lower versions of iOS 7. I want to show different images based on OS version.

For example :- iOS 7 I want to show blue icons same way (Mail app is having)
But, I want to show different icons for iOS 6, 5 users.

Can we use Images.xcassets for this in Xcode 5 or we can create another file with name **@SOMETHING.png** only for iOS 7?

Or we need to write code to load different images based on OS version?

Comment: Since Xcode 5 is still in developer preview, you should ask this on the apple developer forums (devforums.apple.com)

Comment: Too localized because it is a question about Beta software under NDA.

Comment: The whole point of using an asset catalog is that it no longer requires "@something.png". I know it's not an answer but if you're using an asset catalog then why are you asking about a filename prefix.

Comment: Can you please reopen now. Because Xcode 5 is released. And I want to know best solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there is one sample code "*https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ui7kit*". Please check this one these may be helpful to you.